# What is this strange conditional operator syntax?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I recently saw the following in the codebase:

```
bool bRes = (a < b) ? a=b, true : false;
```

If `a < b`, then `a=b` is executed and `bRes` is true.
What exactly is going on here? The docs for conditional operator don't mention anything about chaining expressions.

edit: to be clear I get the conditional operator part, it's the `a=b, true` as a single expression that confused me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eww.  That is a usage of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).  `a=b, true` does precisely what you said.  It executes each expression and results in the value of the last expression.

Comment: +1 Hahahaha... you've not seen a real "eww" use of the comma operator yet. My all-time favorite is in [Subbotin's carryless range coder](http://koders.com/cpp/fidAD810238688D2DDBC02B8FAF0A8EAC8DBD68604D.aspx?s=subbotin#L21). Just look at that line for less than 30 seconds, and then try to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

That is a correct code, but written in a strange style. The language allows to use the comma operator this way.

The equivalent is

```
bool bRes;
if (a < b)
{
 a = b;
 bRes = true;
}
else
 bRes = false;
```

Comment: this is a MUCH better way of writing the same thing. Good job!

Comment: But now it's assignment and not initialization. In the original code, we may well have declared `bRes` to be `const`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Good point. How about `const bool bRes = a < b; if (bRes) a = b;` ?

Comment: @Andrey: Better! Any code of the sort `bool w = condition ? true : false`, or it's `if`-equivalent as in your example, should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: @Andrey: my previous comment is rather about using comma operator inside initializers in general; I agree that this particular example is ugly enough.